# How to create outline on blurred shape in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, blur

Hello I need help creating an outline to a blur shape I managed to blur the shape but I'm just trying to create a an outline to the blurred shape so it stands out more and I cannot seem to do it. The way I blurred the shape was I made a copy of the video and put Gaussian blur filter and tracking matte key to make it blur out the background now when I try to create the outline using properties on the shape it will not create a solid outline. You can see in the picture below for a better understanding . [image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking how to do this in Photoshop, however your example image is in Adobe Premier Pro.

Anyway, this is how I'd do it in Photoshop.

- Copy and paste a section of the background, on a new layer, to make your blurred shape.
- Engage the "pixel lock" in the layers panel.
- Click Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur, to blur the shape.
- Disengage the "pixel lock".
- CTRL+click (or Command+click on Mac) on the layer with the blurred
  shape.  This will select the shape.
- Click Edit > Stroke, and choose a stroke width and colour to stroke the outline of the shape.

Example using the above technique:

[image: Example image of blurred shape outlined]

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming that you are wanting to blur a specific shape within an image (since you specified that you were using Adobe Photoshop). However, you mention that you made a copy of a video and applied a blur.

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you just need to use the selection tool and/or make a quick mask to select your object and then just blur that portion of the image using the blur tool.

Answer (score 0):

create a layer that is a duplicate of the unblurred image, and paint over the shape you will be blurring. Use black or white and color in the part that will have a blurry edge, which you don't want.
blur the second image, and create a mask with the first image, placing it above the blurred layer. The part that you painted black will "disappear," and the blurred part will show through.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the outline just as a box in Illustrator or Photoshop. Illustrator might make the load lighter for Premier Pro.

1. You would make the outline of a box with your desired thickness
2. Make it the exact same dimensions as the blur
3. Just make sure it is on a layer above that blur filter in Premier Pro.